# Getting an exception during createQueueConnection

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

Below is the stack trace of the error .Could some one please suggest what is the error .

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.
The Java(tm) MQI has thrown an exception describing the problem. 
See the linked exception for further information.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor139.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:314)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:228)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:175)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6200)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createProviderXAConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:102)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createXAConnectionInternal(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:364)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAQueueConnectionFactory.createXAQueueConnection(MQXAQueueConnectionFactory.java:138)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedQueueConnection.createConnection(JMSManagedQueueConnection.java:152)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedConnection.<init>(JMSManagedConnection.java:352)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedQueueConnection.<init>(JMSManagedQueueConnection.java:72)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.WMQJMSRAManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(WMQJMSRAManagedConnectionFactory.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(JMSManagedConnectionFactory.java:687)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.WMQJMSRAManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(WMQJMSRAManagedConnectionFactory.java:704)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createManagedConnectionWithMCWrapper(FreePool.java:2167)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1837)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3805)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3081)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1548)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1031)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle.createQueueConnection(JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle.java:85)
    at com.ofss.jms.ejb.EJBJms.createJMSConnection(EJBJms.java:2439)
    at com.ofss.jms.ejb.EJBJms.BeforeProcessResponseMessage(EJBJms.java:697)
    at com.ofss.jms.ejb.EJBJms.responsemsg(EJBJms.java:622)
    at com.ofss.jpoller.model.EJBTimerBean.timeout(EJBTimerBean.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor76.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.TimedObjectWrapper.invokeCallback(TimedObjectWrapper.java:129)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.TimerTaskHandler.doWork(TimerTaskHandler.java:364)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.AlarmListener.executeTaskWithNotification(AlarmListener.java:807)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.AlarmListener.access$700(AlarmListener.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.AlarmListener$TaskWork.doWork(AlarmListener.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.AlarmListener$TaskWork.run(AlarmListener.java:222)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$RunProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:271)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:666)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:490)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:133)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$DoAsProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:338)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:696)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:806)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.ExecutionContextImpl.go(ExecutionContextImpl.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.AlarmListener.fireTask(AlarmListener.java:1416)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.AlarmListener.fired(AlarmListener.java:1334)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.AlarmImpl.callListenerMethod(AlarmImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.timer.GenericTimer.run(GenericTimer.java:229)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$RunProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:267)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:666)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:490)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:133)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$DoAsProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:338)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:696)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:1174)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.AlarmImpl.runListenerAsCJWork(AlarmImpl.java:249)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.am._Alarm.fireAlarm(_Alarm.java:340)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.am._Alarm.run(_Alarm.java:237)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2195;AMQ9546: Error return code received. [1=java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException[null],3=GeneratedConstructorAccessor149.newInstance]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.processESESecurity(JmqiEnvironment.java:987)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:832)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:655)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:167)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor149.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.processESESecurity(JmqiEnvironment.java:906)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/ibm/mq/jmqi/JmqiMQ.isLocal()Z (loaded from file:/scratch/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/installedConnectors/wmq.jmsra.rar/com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@29e46d22) called from class com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI (loaded from file:/scratch/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar by com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader@bda2c581).
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.<init>(ESEJMQI.java:112)
    ... 62 more
```

I am new to this, Could you please guide in understanding the issue over here .Thanks

Comment: Failing code is g_QueueConn = l_QCF.createQueueConnection();

Comment: What version of IBM MQ are you using?   In the last line or mentions both file:/scratch/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/installedConnectors/wmq.jmsra.rar/com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar and file:/scratch/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar why do you have both the rar and jar?

Comment: Looks like reflection is being used to load and invoke a class method. In this case a constructor, which isn't found. As @JoshMc states it may be down to a clash of java classes found in the class path.